# JSP Exception error while converting from String to Int

Tags: java, jsp, exception

There is one class as `X.Java.`In this below two lines I am doing

```
request.getSession.setAttribute("count",String.valueOf(rsp.getCount()));
```

In the above I am getting count from database in `rsp.getCount()`. Here `getcount()` is integer 
type and I am changing to String as `String.valueOf(rsp.getCount()` and setting into one attribute as `count`.

There is one jsp as X.jsp 
Now I am using `getAttribute` and storing the value in `failCount` variable of `string` type.

```
String failCount = request.getSession.getAttribute("count");
```

Now I want to convert this value into integer type for that I wrote this line

```
int countInt = Integer.parseInt(failCount);
```

I am getting error like the one below

```
127039 13-02-26 17:13:35 ERROR http-10.18.2.105-12205-Processor4 - <JSPFilter ServletException> - test.abc.common.filter.JSPFilter.doFilter(JSPFilter.java:111) 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: abc/x.jsp:66 

63:              
64:          } 
65:          String failCount = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("failCount"); 
66:          int failCountint = Integer.parseInt(failCount); 
67:          //System.out.println(failCountint); 
68:           
69:           


Stacktrace: 
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:489) 
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411) 
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308) 
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:399) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:142) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:247) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1105) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:841) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:755) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:396) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:350) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Can you share your JSP code and try printing the value of `failCount` string in console from JSP ?

Comment: if i comment this line int failCountint = Integer.parseInt(failCount);  then it was working fine and giving output also but when i am trying to convert to integer i am getting error above

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting session in HttpRequest

```
request.getSession.setAttribute("count",String.valueOf(rsp.getCount()));
```

Is this java file is servlet then it will work well.

One more thing make sure rsp.getCount() is not return "null".

In JSP file

```
String failCount = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("failCount"); 
int failCountint = Integer.parseInt(failCount);
```

why are you using request.getSession() instead of session, and you are trying to get failcount instead of count

Try this

```
String failCount = session.getAttribute("count").toString();
int countInt = Integer.parseInt(failCount);
```

I think it may help full...

Comment: ok..got the problem i am not checking for the null...i am getting as null in the String failCount..thank you folks for helping me..god bless you all

Answer (score 0):

Setting value is session:

```
request.getSession.setAttribute("count",String.valueOf(rsp.getCount()));
```

Reading value from session:

```
String failCount = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("failCount");
```

While setting the value in session, you are calling it `count` and while reading the value from JSP, you are calling it `failCount`.

Comment: If your problem is solved, it is always better to up-vote correct answers and mark appropriate answer as ACCEPTED.

Answer (score 0):

I think failCount is null that why 
int failCountint = Integer.parseInt(failCount);

So please use 
System.out.println(failCount);

And also use try catch block around error line.